# Spring Batch Chunk Size issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using springbatch to read some data from a source, generate a set of Json based on this data and write it to a target table. I have set reader.setFetchSize, reader.setPageSize as 100 in my JdbcPagingItemReader. Suppose if I have more than 100 data in a single batch execution, the reader reads only upto first 100 data and batch execution stops after executing this data and the remaining set of data remains unread.
Isnt it supposed to read the whole set of data in different pages?

How can I correct such that if there are 250 records at a time, batch reads this whole set of data.(the record size may depend on data generated at that time, so cannot keep a fixed value)

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your configuration looks good. setPageSize should be enough. Maybe your database doesn't support paging? Try to switch to JdbcCursorItemReader and use the chunk size parameter of the step builder.